# Printing list item with a change in geometry

Tags: lists

I have changed the page size using the geometry package.  Have been using list to print a tag and an indented paragraph.  Bet the text in the `\item` is getting printed outside the text area of the document.  That is, the ontents in `[#2]` is getting printed to the left of the left margin.

I would also like the paragraph starting on the next line to `TAG.xxx`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment {Spar} { O{0.3cm} m }
  {
    \list {}
      {
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      }
    \item[[#2]]
  }
    { \endlist }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\geometry { paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
             left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm,
             includehead, includefoot }

\begin{document}

\begin{Spar}{TAG.1999-DEF8}
  PAR.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; "Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians."  Vol. 1-2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
\end{Spar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\item[[#2]]` has optional argument `[#2` then prints `]` did you intend `\item[{#2}]`

Comment: I want to enclose `#2` with square braces when `#2` is printed.

Comment: that isn't what your code does (well it accidentally almost does that, but the `[` is part of the label and the `]` is part of the following text (see the version in my answer)

Comment: oh I just saw you want the text following label, I could add that to my answer but why can't you simply use the style=nextline option as in the answer to your last question?????

Comment: I know that solution, but I am now playing with using `\list`.

Comment: Incidentally this is unrelated to `geometry` the list settings you had would overprint the left margin whatever page size you set in `geometry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would find this easier using `enumitem`, but basically this is a description list, if you copy more of the `description` setup you will keep the label within the margins.

[image]

I added bold (copied from `description`) to highlight the label, but obviously that could be removed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment {Spar} { O{0.3cm} m }
  {
    \list {}
      {
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}
        \renewcommand*\makelabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \normalfont\bfseries ##1}
      }
    \item[{[#2]}]
  }
    { \endlist }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\geometry { b5paper, 
  left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm,
  includehead, includefoot }

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{Spar}{TAG.1999-DEF8}
  PAR.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; "Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians."  Vol. 1-2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
\end{Spar}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Or with a newline (which as shown in a previous answer is *much* easier to do with `enumitem` which is doing the same thing more or less, but packaged as `style=newline`)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment {Spar} { O{0.3cm} m }
  {
    \list {}
      {
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}
        \renewcommand*\makelabel[1]{\rlap{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\hspace*{\labelsep}
              \normalfont\bfseries ##1\endgraf\mbox{}
            }}
          \hspace{\leftmargin}
      }}
  \item[{[#2]}]
  }
    { \endlist }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\geometry { b5paper, 
  left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm,
  includehead, includefoot }

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{Spar}{TAG.1999-DEF8}
  PAR.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; "Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians."  Vol. 1-2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
\end{Spar}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are correct about `enumitem` being easier and have used that approach.  But I do not want to miss all these page setting details which would be useful for me to understand.

Comment: all the `\list` parameters are settable via the `enumitem` interface (and better documented there) @Ragonese

Comment: Have been looking to find the code for `description` you mentioned that I can look up.  Is that in `enumitem` ?  Which part of the `enumitem` file should I look for documentation and the use with `\list` ?  Have browsed it for a while but not really identified the important parts.

Comment: @Ragonese `description` is defined in `article` class so `texdoc classes.pdf` and the `list` environment is defined in the latex format so `texdoc source2e` The _whole point_ of `enumitem` is you do not use `\list` you use a higher level interface and it constructs the `\list` setup.